# Nest IIF with query as true statement

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am writing another query where I would like to say, if Block A is selected, show cell values between two times. Is something like below possible?

***select
iif(@Block='A', select CellID from holdingdock where TxnDateGMT between '6:00' and '14:30', '',
iif(@Block='B', select CellID from holdingdock where TxnDateGMT between '14:00' and '22:30',''))***

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can use the nested IFF statement in the query.In the below link there is example of using nested iff statement,it may help you:-
https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-sql-iif-statement/

Answer (score 0):

It's better to write code like this :

```
Select Case When @Block='A' Then select CellID from holdingdock where TxnDateGMT between '6:00' and '14:30' When @Block='B' Then select CellID from holdingdock where TxnDateGMT between '14:00' and '22:30' Else '' END
```

OR

```
Select Case @Block When 'A' Then select CellID from holdingdock where TxnDateGMT between '6:00' and '14:30' When 'B' Then select CellID from holdingdock where TxnDateGMT between '14:00' and '22:30' ELSE '' END
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want simple boolean logic in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select CellID
from holdingdock
where (@Block = 'A' and TxnDateGMT between '6:00' and '14:30') or
      (@Block = 'B' and TxnDateGMT between '14:00' and '22:30')
```